# Django Project not running

Tags: python, django

I have a simple django project. Installed python,django and mysql database in my ubuntu to run this project. In order to run my project I am trying to sync database first. But when I am trying command **"python manage.py syndb"** I am getting following errors:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 429, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 139, in __init__
    logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 562, in configure
    'filter %r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_false': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse': No module named RequireDebugFalse
```

I am very new to python and django. doing it first time..

Comment: looks like you have a line in your logging config that has dependencies that are not included in the settings.py file.

Comment: First of all, if you are new to python, you maybe should learn some python befor starting with a framework like Django. It seems like you are importing a module which isnt available. What way have you installed Django? Btw: Have you already tried this?  https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/135/

Comment: I installed django using sudu apt-get install pyhton-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse` appeared in Django 1.4.0. Could it be you have an older Django version installed ?

Comment: so how can I upgrade to 1.4

Comment: If you are new do Django I assume you just started with a new Proeject. Just download the newest Version (1.6) from the website and install it. I think you can keep the most apps and files for the new version.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the comment, you installed Django from your distro's repository. Those versions are often old, and indeed it looks like you have installed version 1.3, which is now three versions out of date.

You should remove that version (with `apt-get remove`) and install the current version from the Python package index, via `pip install django`. You will probably need to install `pip` first, which you *can* do with `apt-get`.